# How to use negative regex matching with grep -E?

Tags: regex, grep

I'm using the following regex via `grep -E` to match a specific string of chars via `|` pipe.

```
$ git log <more switches here> | grep -E "match me"
```

Output:

```
match me once
match me twice
```

What I'm really looking for a is a negative match (return all output lines that don't contain the specified string something like the following but `grep` doesn't like it:

```
$ git log <more switches here> | grep -E "^match me"
```

desired output:

```
whatever 1
whatever 2
```

here is the full output that comes back from the command line:

```
match me once
match me twice
whatever 1
whatever 2
```

How to do arrive at the desired output per a negative regex match?

Comment: `awk '!/^match me/' file`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `-v` option which inverts the matches, selecting *non-matching* lines

```
grep -v 'match me'
```

Another option is to use `-P` which interprets the pattern as a Perl regular expression.

```
grep -P '^((?!match me).)*$'
```